# How to select rows from two tables in laravel and return them as a single list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two tables,one is called patient_payments and the other is patient_billing.i now want to select all the rows from each table and then present them as a single list in my webpage.I am using laravel framework and i have used raw query as follows

```
$items = DB::select(DB::raw('select * from patient_payments pp,patient_billings pb'));
```

One table has three rows and the other five rows and i was expecting two get eight rows but the query returns 14 rows which is wrong.Any idea what is wrong with my query is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a one-to-one relationship?

Comment: Is there any relationship between the 2 tables?

Comment: There is no direct relationship between them but each of them has a one-many relationship with a table called patients and thus each of them has a foreign key called patient_id

Comment: Are `patient_payments` and `patient_billings` tables have the same total columns? Are those tables have the same structure?

Comment: Yes,they both have the same number of columns.

Comment: Use the `UNION ALL` command.  See http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both tables have the same number of columns, you can use `union()` method like this:

```
$items = DB::table('patient_payments')
    ->union(DB::table('patient_billings'))
    ->get();
```

Read more about [Laravel Query Builder: `union()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#unions) here.

Hope this help.